# Can we give downvoted questions a chance?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

When we ask a question that gets downvoted for some reason, then we edit it to make it more helpful, the question is not "new" anymore (it is deep in the unanswered questions section), so the question doesn't get much attention.

Is there any way for these questions (like mine: {Not telling unless you look at edit history}) to get some attention or get pushed back to the top because they are edited? Or is there anything we/I can do because asking the edited question is kind of a duplicate?

Comment: For those watching those tags, an edited question actually does come up to the front page.

Comment: What if they are not watching?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't see it, but that works to your benefit; I don't know VB (and would run at the sight of it), so it wouldn't make sense for me to see it.  I've got filters set on different languages.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Why? Getting those questions pushed back to the top means that other questions are pushed out of the way. Is that fair?

Comment: When a question is edited it goes to the top of "active" questions for its various tags. Personally, I find the active page has way too many trivial edits for it to be useful for very active tags, but that's another issue entirely. It is not "new".

Comment: How is the question unclear/not useful?/why do you dislike it?

Comment: edited questions are not new - why should questions you want go to the top in place of everyone else?  What makes your question so important?

Comment: On the question you use as an example Hans tried to explain that you need to add your code that handles the drop or the mouse events. On your question the downvotes are explained and you didn't add anything useful that address the comment. If questions that are edited should be brought to attention again to the users who already looked at it, your question wouldn't benefit from it because nothing had changed...

Comment: Ok. Edited questions are not new.  -Deleting comments...-

Comment: And I have edited the question to say there is no code. How can i add (no code) to the question? And I didn't know you needed (no code).

Answer (score 8):

This topic was discussed a very long time ago, and sporadically since. The overall recurring theme is that you should ask your question the correct way in the first round. It shouldn't need any fixing up once posted because it was expected that the author took a good amount of time preparing it.

Users are encouraged to vote on content. When they view content that they feel warrants a downvote and issue one, they are not suddenly responsibly for the future of that post. They voted on the question as they found it. If the question receives an edit which makes it become well received, then time will reverse the votes as other users see content they feel warrants an upvote.

If it is just one post out of a history of good posts then there is nothing to worry about. There are no answers on this specific one so you can just remove it and move on. Or, you can let it stand and see how it fares. Time will also be a very large factor in these posts, and while there does tend to be a flurry of activity up front, if the question is relevant to a larger audience it will attract upvotes and positive attention in the long run.

However, if the post is not just one out of a history of good posts then that may be indicative of an issue with posting questions in general. This tends to be the path that users who end up hitting the question ban hit. In this case, it is very important to do some research about how to pose good questions and also to do some research to ensure that the questions posed are both reproducible and well explained or shown by example.

Comment: This saved me a lot of typing in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

It might be deep in the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) tab list, but it gets back at the top of the [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) tab.

If I am interested in edited and improved material I look at the active tab, if hunting for something I have not read before, then I look at the [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) tab. If your improved post would be at the top of the newest tab as well we could just remove the active tab.

There is enough out there on the newest tab that looks like I have already seen it in some form. It is not necessary to add stuff **there** that I **have** actually already seen.

The mechanism to get extra attention is to put a bounty on the question. Maybe you should see that as the cost of not properly preparing to ask the question, resulting in it initially being downvoted.

Comment: But what if you do not have enough rep for a bounty

Comment: Then you cannot hand  out a bounty and you are stuck. That is price for not paying attention and being new to a site, by not learning how things work. Still no reason to force something on a 'newest' tab visitor who clearly selected not to watch the 'active' tab.